# Is pandas.timestamp python datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I was working on time submodule of astropy. It can parse python `datetime` objects.

When I pass a `pandas.Timestamp` object astropy.time.Time thinks it's a `datetime` object.

Tracking down the issue, I found this.

```
>>> t = pandas.Timestamp('2018-01-01')
>>> isinstance(t, datetime.datetime)
True
```

My question is, why is `isinstance` returning `True`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because it inherits from datetime.datetime

`class _Timestamp(__datetime.datetime):`

so it is an instance of a `datetime.datetime` ...

Answer (score 0):

> TimeStamp is the pandas equivalent of python’s Datetime and is interchangable with it in most cases.

See [pandas.Timestamp documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timestamp.html)